# Why the routes in main config not loaded if you add routes in other config file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm setting up a spring cloud gateway application that has 3 environments (DEV, QA, PROD). All main routes are placed on the main config file but I have other routes that need to be declared in the environment config file. Please check the sample config file below:

test.yaml(main)

```
 spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: test-routes-1
          uri: http://testing1.com/
        - id: test-routes
          uri: http://testing.com/
```

test-dev.yaml

```
 spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: test-routes
          uri: http://testing-dev.com/
```

When I deploy the application with this config file only the dev routes will be available and the other routes in the main config are not available. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behaviour. There is no way to work around this AFAIK.

> Profile-specific properties are loaded from the same locations as standard application.properties, with profile-specific files always overriding the non-specific ones, whether or not the profile-specific files are inside or outside your packaged jar.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Comment: Ok. But it's working with properly with Zuul gateway before we move to spring cloud gateway, we have profile specific and non-profile specific routes. I just thought this should be working also on spring cloud gateway.

Comment: That's because lists are being overwritten (which is used for the `routes` configuration by SC Gateway), and maps will be merged (which is used for the `routes` configuration by Zuul).
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-complex-type-merge

Comment: Ok. I understand the issue now. Thanks, @TYsewyn.